# WARNING: CPU random generator seem to be failing, disable hardware random number generation

Tags: 20.04

I get a CPU random generator warning advising me to disable hardware random number generation

`WARNING: CPU random generator seem to be failing, disable hardware random number generation`

```
WARNING: RDRND generated: 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff WARNING: CPU random generator seem to be failing, disable hardware random number generation WARNING: RDRND generated: 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff
```

This happens whenever I run an application on the terminal.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and my processor is AMD Ryzen 7 3700X 8-Core.
What do I do? Should I be worried?

Comment: AMD bug, should be bios update available.  Link one of few,  https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2019/10/how-a-months-old-amd-microcode-bug-destroyed-my-weekend/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have same problem you need upgrade your BIOS it's very important and it's very serious problem.

> AMD bug, should be bios update available.

Thanks @crip659